# Peewee select Decimal field?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, peewee

I have the following request using Peewee library:

```
return Products.select(Products.price, Products.sku, Products.manufacturer_id).where(Products.sku == article).get()
```

Where `Products.price` is field with type `decimal(15,4)` in MySQL

This is Model:

```
class Products(peewee.Model):
    product_id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    sku = peewee.CharField()
    model = peewee.CharField()
    price = peewee.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=4)
    manufacturer_id = peewee.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        database = get_db_connection()
        table_name = 'oc_product'
```

When I run query was described above I get an error:

```
Error has occurred: Cannot convert b'6403.0000' to Decimal
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Who can help me?

Comment: Problem is in `Products.price`

Answer (score 0):

I believe there was a bug in Peewee with Python 3. Let me know if this patch addresses your issue:

https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/cd07f4e01a1262166d8944736e11d0681fb76214